# Finding number of strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many ternary strings of length 10 that contain exactly 2 1s and 3 2s.
Since it must contain exactly 2 1s and 3 2s the other 5 spaces must be 0s.
I was thinking it's 2!3!5!  But apparently it's 10!/(2!3!5!) Can someone explain why we need the 10!

Answer (score 1):

Out of the $10$ positions choose two of them to hold $1$, then out of the remaining $8$ positions choose three postions to hold $2$ and the remaining five positions are all $0$. Hence the number of ways is
$$
\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{5}=\frac{10!}{2!3!5!}.
$$